# Change gridview row image on Touch

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a gridview 3 x 3 in Android and I populate each row of it with an ImageView using custom adapter, on each ImageView I am setting a different imageview.setImageResource(drawable).
On each ImageView I also add an onTouchListener (inside the adapter) that on action Down changes the image resource to a new one and on Action Up it sets the old image back so it emulates a button press.

Everything works O.K. except when I click on any row it only changes the image of the last row instead of changing the image resource of the clicked cell. Now I know that this is probably due to some fundamental lack of knowledge of how Android works, but can anyone give me a hint of what I might be doing wrong?

Update. this is my code of the adapter:

```
public class ListImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private Integer[] mThumbIds;
    private int w;
    protected int category;
    private int movefact;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ListImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] ims) {
        mContext = c;
        mThumbIds = ims;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext) {
                @Override
                protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec,
                                         int heightMeasureSpec) {
                    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
                    w = getMeasuredWidth();
                }
            };

            int width;


            width = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 4;

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width, width / 3));
            imageView.setScaleType(
                    ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }


                imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckborderlistbig2);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

               // Log.i("IMAGE", "motion event: " + imageView.toString());
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ghost1);

                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ghost1);

                        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

                return imageView;
        //}

    }
}
```

Comment: absolutely as soon as a I get home, I was impatient I had to ask

Comment: this is my update with the code